# Exact Diagonalization, Jordan-Winger Transformation and the Second Quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, many-body, ising-model

I am currently study the quantum Ising model with the guide of my supervisor in an undergraduate project. Since my undergraduate courses didn't cover this, I use this paper to as the main material https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.09208 . However, I got lost in several concepts. Take an 1-dimensional Ising chain as our study model. My supervisor said since the exact diagonalization is inapplicable as the dimension of our Hilbert space increases, we use the Jordan-Wigner transformation to transform the spin operator representation into the fermonic operator representation and this simplify the whole problem. But why does this make things simpler? According to my unerstanding, even we represent our spin system in terms of fermonic operators, to solve the system, we still diagonalize the Hamiltonian matrix $\mathbf{H}_{k}$ which gives us the energy eigenvalues $\epsilon_{k\pm}=\pm\epsilon_k$ with
\begin{equation}
  \epsilon_k=|\mathbf{R}_k|=2J\sqrt{\left (\cos{k}-\frac{h}{J}\right)^2+\varkappa^2\sin^2{k}},
\end{equation}
as incidated in the paper. Is this not the exact diagonalization?

Could anyone help me clearify these ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to spell out your question in just a bit more detail, then it will be clear what the answer is. You're considering a one-dimensional spin chain with $N$ spins, each of which is a two-level system. That means your Hamiltonian can be regarded as a $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix of the form
$$
\hat{H} = \sum_{nm} |n\rangle H_{nm} \langle m|
$$
where $H_{nm}$ is the indicated $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix, and $|n\rangle$ represents any complete orthonormal basis you'd like. If your goal is to find the $2^N$ eigenstates and eigenvalues of $\hat{H}$, one way is to simply diagonalize $H_{nm}$. However, as your advisor has indicated, this is usually a hopeless task: since the Hamiltonian is $2^N \times 2^N$, diagonalization will be *exponentially hard* as a function of $N$. You may be able to diagonalize $\hat{H}$ by hand for $N = 1$ or $2$ (or even $N=3$ if you are extremely patient), and probably as high as $N = 15$ using your laptop, but you would be hard pressed to diagonalize the Hamiltonian for $N=20$ or $30$.

On the other hand, the quantum Ising model has a solution in terms of free fermionic operators. This means that you can write your Hamiltonian in the form
$$
\hat{H} = \sum_{\alpha \beta} c^{\dagger}_{\alpha} h_{\alpha \beta} c_{\beta}
$$
where $h_{\alpha \beta}$ is an $N \times N$ matrix. $\hat{H}$ is still $2^N \times 2^N$, but having a free fermion representation means that it can be compressed into just an $N \times N$ matrix, which you can diagonalize for extremely large $N$ on your computer. But there's a further simplification: if $\hat{H}$ is *translation invariant*, then you can diagonalize it by hand using a Fourier transform. This is how the spectrum in your post was arrived at. (I encourage you to check that the Fourier transform does not work so cleanly in the full $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix $H_{nm}$ as it does in the smaller $N \times N$ matrix $h_{\alpha \beta}$.)

Comment: Thank you so much, Zack! This makes the whole idea much clear and organizaed. So according to your explanation, the benefit of these manipulations is that we transfer the problem of diagonalizing a $2^N\times2^N$ matrix $H_{nm}$ to a problem of diagonalizing a $N\times N$ matrix $h_{\alpha \beta}$ while we still use the exact diagonalization to find the spectrum. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Usually, when someone says the phrase "exact diagonalization", they have in mind brute-force diagonalization of an exponentially large matrix using their computer. In this case, it's true that you're diagonalizing the smaller matrix $h_{\alpha \beta}$, but I wouldn't call it "exact diagonalization" if you're doing it by hand.